# Chrome extension:How to store data locally?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I tried to do very basic to do list chrome extension.
When i append the value from textarea, it is shown on extension but if i close the extension and then click it , appended value is not there. 
How can i store it?

[image: when i open the extension]

[image: after adding]

[image: i closed extension and then clicked]

```js
// chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab){

$("#button").click(function() {
  var userList = $('#textarea').val();
  localStorage.setItem('userlist', 'userlist');
  $('#textarea').val('');
  $('#list').append('<p>' + localStorage.getItem('userlist', 'userlist'));
});

// });
```

```css
#textarea {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 200px;
  resize: none;
  outline: none;
}
#button {
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  background: #333;
  height: 24px;
  width: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: 7px;
}
#list {
  border: 1px solid #333;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea rows="1" id="textarea"></textarea>
<button id="button">Add</button>
<div id="list"></div>
```

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage

Comment: Tried but somehow could not make it work.Then i just need to check my code.

Comment: We cannot help you to correct code that you haven't shown us!!

Comment: Can't see any localStorage usage here.

Comment: You're setting a localStorage variable to the string "userlist" .. not very useful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. The answer is [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/tr/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

Basically you can use like this > localStorage.setItem('myCat', 'Tom');

Here below you can see how did i use it.

```js
// just created  a list variable where i append my values.
// and then set the list to localStorage.
// then just wrote if statement to check if we have something on local storage already saved.

//all codes here

// chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab){

$("#button").click(function() {
  var userList = $('#textarea').val();
  $('#textarea').val('');
  $('#list').append('<p>' + userList);

  var list = $("#list").html();
  localStorage.setItem('list', list);
  return false;

});

if (localStorage.getItem('list')) {
  $('#list').html(localStorage.getItem('list'));
}

// });
```

```css
#textarea {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 200px;
  resize: none;
  outline: none;
}
#button {
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  background: #333;
  height: 24px;
  width: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: 7px;
}
#list {
  border: 1px solid #333;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea rows="1" id="textarea"></textarea>
<button id="button">Add</button>
<div id="list"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)?

```
localStorage.setItem('myCat', 'Tom');
```

Comment: Yea but making a mistake , cos could not make it  work

Comment: hmmn.. my next thought would be to try to use a cookie variable, but that may also require its own configuration.